# How is it valid to say : "we are also be talking about"

Tags: grammar, meaning, tense

So, I read the sentence *"But we **are** also **be talking** about ...[a subject]"* somewhere and at that moment I just thought it's a mistake. However I googled it and interestingly found many similar cases!
Now, would you let me know how is this sentence composed and what's the role of 'be' in this sentence, please.
I've already heard something like "we will also be talking about", but how should I interpret this case?

And the last but not least question is that is it possible to extend it to other tenses and say something like "we were also be talking about..."?

**Please feel free to edit the title of this question and remove this sentence consequently as I could not find a better one.**

Comment: I Googled [*"But we are also **be** talking about"*](https://www.google.co.uk/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=M1kYVKfFBuuq8wf07YLYAQ&gws_rd=ssl#q=%22But+we+are+also+be+talking+about%22) and got just ***seven*** results (two being for this very question, and at least one duplicate entry in the others). Comparing that to ***about 522,000 results*** for [*"But we are also talking about"*](https://www.google.co.uk/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=VVkYVIveNuuq8wf07YLYAQ&gws_rd=ssl#q=%22But+we+are+also+talking+about%22), it seems to me this question is General Reference even for ELL.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a typographical or transcription error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this is a mistake. I can see 6 Google results for ["we are also be talking about"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22we+are+also+be+talking+about%22), but four of those are from the same (possibly Chinese?) source, one also looks to be Chinese, and the remaining link is an automatically-generated transcript from a video, and therefore cannot be trusted to be correct.

The correct phrasing is "But we are also talking about...". The extra **"be"** is wrong because the verb "to be" is already present in the form of "are".

To answer your remaining questions: "we **will** also be talking about" is correct because "will" is necessary to signal that we are talking about the future. Other tenses don't use "be" like this, so "we were also be talking about" is incorrect.

Comment: @mok I only get 18 results for _we are be talking_ and I agree with ZsigE; this is not a common usage. _We will be talking..._, _we are talking..._, _we are going to be talking..._, _we have been talking..._ are all 'normal' uses. So +1 from me.

Comment: @Frank> First, thank you for the time you've take to answer my question. However, please take a look at [this](http://www.whur.com/fitness-fridays/its-fitness-friday-dr-judy-staveley/) web page that is obviously made by a native speaker that makes more confident about the correctness of the phrase. I wish I could get an answer from a native speaker too.

Comment: @Frank> Oh, [this](http://www.wealden.gov.uk/Wealden/Residents/Parking_Streets_and_Travel/Car_Parks/Assets_Car_Parking_Status.aspx) makes me even more confident that the sentence is correct. Note that this is an official website of the UK government, please! As you told, I think it's not too common, but it's correct. And if it's correct, how?What's the meaning?

Comment: @mok As far as I can tell, the "we are be talking" is either a non-native error, or just an error in general.  The only dialect of English I can think of that might get close is African American Vernacular English, which would render it something like "we be talking about", but neither of your links are written in it.

Comment: @mok Not everyone in the UK are native speakers, and even those that are don't always take the time to proofread what they have written. Both of these look like mistakes that should have been caught during proofreading. I don't like to say "That's wrong", because language changes, but this usage is, at the moment, as close to "wrong" as you'll get.

Comment: @Frank and @Tory> Your answers make sense and to make sure, I'll just make a final check with my teacher tomorrow and report the results here.

Comment: @mok I've emailed Wealden Council to ask them if that is a commonly used phrase in East Sussex these days. Hopefully we might a reply.

Comment: @mok I am a native speaker of British English, if that makes any difference. The Wealden Council page looks to me like they started with the phrase "What we will be doing" and then tried to change it to "What we are doing", but left the "be" in by mistake.

Comment: @mok ZsigE - I agree entirely with that comment regarding a badly done update to the wording.

Comment: @ZsigE> Obviously it makes a big difference, and I think now remains no doubt that it's a mistake.

Comment: @mok I have received an impressively rapid reply from Wealden Council which suggests that they will be correcting the sentence in the near future.

Comment: @Frank> That's great.